# How do I draw an HICON?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, icons

I want to display an icon in the system tray.

It seems like it should be so simple, but I can't figure out how to create an `HICON` and draw to it! All the "compatible bitmaps", "compatible DCs", etc. stuff are really confusing me.

How do I draw an icon?

Comment: Are you trying to load a static icon into an HICON or are you trying to draw a dynamic/changing icon in the tray?

Comment: @Zac: Most certainly the latter. :)

Comment: Are you using MFC, WTL, Qt?  Or just straight Win32?

Comment: @Zac: Did you look at my answer by any chance?

Comment: AAAHHH..  I didn't realize you answered your own question! ( but you haven't accepted it, thats what threw me off.)  I had already upvoted it because it was a good answer, but didn't know if it met the original posters criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into too much detail, you can use the following C++ class.

It uses the [Windows Template Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/), but it should be very simple to convert it into plain C.

```
using namespace WTL;
class CIconDC : public CDC
{
public:
    HBITMAP hBmpOld;

    CIconDC(int cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),  // width
            int cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),  // height
            HDC templateDC = CClientDC(NULL))  // automatically calls ReleaseDC
    {
        this->CreateCompatibleDC(templateDC);
        hBmpOld = this->SelectBitmap(CreateCompatibleBitmap(templateDC, cx, cy));
    }

    ~CIconDC() { DeleteObject(this->SelectBitmap(hBmpOld)); }

    HICON CreateIcon() const
    {
        // temporarily swap bitmaps to get handle of current bitmap
        HBITMAP hBitmap = this->GetCurrentBitmap();
        ICONINFO ii = { TRUE, 0, 0, hBitmap, hBitmap };
        return CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
    }
};
```

Using the class is **really** easy:

```
CIconDC dc;
dc.LineTo(10, 10);  // for example -- you can do whatever you want with the DC
CIcon hIcon = dc.CreateIcon();  // converted to an HICON!
```